# How to sort complete wifi list with unique higher strength in Android Wifi?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am not able to sort the wifi list, I am getting duplicate wifi SSIDs so I want get list of unique SSIDs which has higher strength. You can see my following code but not getting correct wifi list.

```
List<ScanResult> results = mWifiManager.getScanResults();

    int size = results.size();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < results.size(); k++) {
                if (results.get(i).SSID.equals(results.get(k).SSID)) {
                    if (results.get(k).level > results.get(i).level) {
                        results.remove(i);
                    } else {
                        results.remove(k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

merge `ScanResults` using `HashMap` in which key will be `String` SSID. just add check for existence of previously added `ScanResult` (in iteration), then compare both `level` values

edit:

```
List<ScanResult> results = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
HashMap<String, ScanResult> filtered = new HashMap<String, ScanResult>();
for(ScanResult sc : results){
    ScanResult prevScanResultOrNull = filtered.get(sc.SSID);
    // compare lever with previous ScanResult,
    // insert bigger value under SSID key, they are same
    if(prevScanResultOrNull!=null)
        filtered.put(prevScanResultOrNull.SSID, // or sc.SSID, whatever
            prevScanResultOrNull.level > sc.level ? 
                prevScanResultOrNull : sc);
    // no SSID in HashMap, so just put as highest value
    else
        filtered.put(sc.SSID, sc);
}
```

edit2:

if you still want to use `List` interface then:

```
results = new ArrayList<ScanResult>(filtered.values());
```

Comment: I didn't get you, can you give me anyone example.